# BSpline: construct surface from enclosing contours

Tags: splines, geometric-transform

I'm aiming to construct 3D shape from profiles (typical archaeological drawing stuff: front, side and top profiles views). Through several operation, I now have BSpline curves, which should define enclosed the aimed surfaces. But I have an hard time getting the surfaces. The following code make a great job in most of the cases (80%), but also produce some artefacts, which I'm not able to bypass.

Here the Impasse I'm stuck in. First 4 BSplines "contours" enclosing a surface:

```
startSplPts = {{0.`, 
0.5564647707269739`, -0.3208040243751072`}, {0.2906475421020172`, 
0.5568608488046674`, -0.32552130235453397`}, {0.5810467666105904`,
 0.5579723731928984`, -0.33836163544930986`},{0.8710304793368053`, 
0.5597729956629763`, -0.35842255005773765`}, {1.1604886322495584`,
 0.5622412231668914`, -0.3849567752410155`}, {1.4492784990862067`,
 0.565386732132466`, -0.41795880971704186`}, {1.7372912700069125`,
 0.5692386568267089`, -0.4570972636979199`}, {2.0245288015307996`,
 0.5737251351405537`, -0.501513706599526`}, {2.3108766291791385`, 
0.578884086056324`, -0.5512992070080414`}, {2.5962594891980664`, 
0.5846972420464744`, -0.6062732145606502`}, {2.880717675736831`, 
0.5910989076290536`, -0.6657868331189597`}, {3.1641012202737664`, 
0.5981142817926784`, -0.7301689585954927`}, {3.4464007293117542`, 
0.6057139206193148`, -0.7990821862383872`}, {3.7276465820239864`, 
0.6138113527826786`, -0.8721241946108985`}, {4.007689092846585`, 
0.6224372462100423`, -0.94960002645292`}, {4.286517147888269`, 
0.6315036688752834`, -1.0312865507844855`}, {4.564128746041064`, 
0.6409629718216421`, -1.1169751932575014`}, {4.840410813379226`, 
0.6507492020164158`, -1.2068267722363666`}, {5.115316705408859`, 
0.6607800560108278`, -1.3007747366002782`}, {5.388849575380602`, 
0.6709453682774605`, -1.3986357692415439`}, {5.6608521540832335`, 
0.6811191668451028`, -1.5006749432241118`}, {5.931260137921809`, 
0.691112715372954`, -1.6068815417537383`}, {6.200073658861224`, 
0.7007234940742878`, -1.7170942344381002`}, {6.467123191014704`, 
0.7096321021672389`, -1.8315750154567758`}, {6.732273622291717`, 
0.7173104199020311`, -1.950470015378068`}, {6.995639996060661`, 
0.7233878865810005`, -2.0733580498431987`}, {7.25676418762396`, 
0.7266250329570602`, -2.2010356471808668`}, {7.513946156126845`, 
0.7251176676800767`, -2.336481121627651`}, {7.765860669125019`, 
0.7153977855549717`, -2.481145741322931`}, {7.889512685356113`, 
0.7052182726649645`, -2.5568452517578755`}, {8.01113807825938`, 
0.688237866075063`, -2.634537457920848`}, {8.070765525371321`, 
0.675001364915045`, -2.6738659073606565`}, {8.129038312297684`, 
0.6564716919448729`, -2.7130988121102284`}, {8.185368767635902`, 
0.6316333715340802`, -2.7516834192361284`}, {8.240321708774308`, 
0.6030461065943662`, -2.7896782912256963`}};
endSplPts = {{0.`, 
7.720322044320179`, -69.27361901350118`}, {0.4990069631342987`, 
7.720431458683134`, -69.27361901350118`}, {0.9980129637832413`, 
7.720705246378976`, -69.27361901350118`}, {1.497018855870793`, 
7.721134760881178`, -69.27361901350116`}, {1.9960246221397906`, 
7.72169150673133`, -69.27361901350115`}, {2.495030268742077`, 
7.722347576203068`, -69.27361901350118`}, {2.9940358208927607`, 
7.723072241105128`, -69.27361901350116`}, {3.4930413272442635`, 
7.723827935915143`, -69.27361901350116`}, {3.992046851015779`, 
7.724571968845284`, -69.27361901350118`}, {4.491052460189091`, 
7.725255957648798`, -69.27361901350118`}, {4.990058225224607`, 
7.725813646300996`, -69.27361901350118`}, {5.4890641392147295`, 
7.726213102505395`, -69.27361901350116`}, {5.988070190655596`, 
7.726352855497343`, -69.27361901350116`}, {6.487076214518892`, 
7.7261477837847785`, -69.27361901350116`}, {6.986081854484544`, 
7.725504392444297`, -69.27361901350118`}, {7.485086471799769`, 
7.724310984883744`, -69.27361901350116`}, {7.9840888622474635`, 
7.722402931174836`, -69.27361901350118`}, {8.483087115266212`, 
7.719624014432627`, -69.27361901350119`}, {8.982078162688106`, 
7.715767748447002`, -69.27361901350116`}, {9.481056867348888`, 
7.710555298200768`, -69.27361901350116`}, {9.980014676095706`, 
7.703641248155557`, -69.27361901350115`}, {10.47893941356706`, 
7.69465693968755`, -69.27361901350118`}, {10.97781091821196`, 
7.683099944733437`, -69.27361901350118`}, {11.476590085329242`, 
7.668099353629385`, -69.27361901350116`}, {11.975216341759424`, 
7.648690805702531`, -69.27361901350116`}, {12.473570221040669`, 
7.623276901840595`, -69.27361901350116`}, {12.971433505039167`, 
7.58965976973755`, -69.27361901350116`}, {13.468258022773604`, 
7.543279100664228`, -69.27361901350116`}, {13.962586250768304`, 
7.475933953702292`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.20801845655621`, 
7.4311235705218595`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.449538103431603`, 
7.3688605307567965`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.56611747585565`, 
7.324770453902576`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.678913276778255`, 
7.27205766453889`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.78770476436185`, 
7.211005605748785`, -69.27361901350116`}, {14.896497028547758`, 
7.149953095788039`, -69.27361901350116`}};
runningAlongSplPts1 = {{0.`, 
0.5564647707269736`, -0.3208040243751072`}, {0.`, 
0.6823652750720115`, -0.530975948785415`}, {0.`, 
0.8049023022348158`, -0.7431139371748936`}, {0.`, 
0.9236710427931546`, -0.9573940792349581`}, {0.`, 
1.0342082201259748`, -1.1759696632385188`}, {0.`, 
1.2377852886296616`, -1.6212864804374516`}, {0.`, 
1.418054086039488`, -2.0769081795923494`}, {0.`, 
1.706820531904982`, -3.013106929106064`}, {0.`, 
1.9695701395590866`, -3.956917345423572`}, {0.`, 
2.2055454910169265`, -4.908033928629447`}, {0.`, 
2.415477352441144`, -5.865259347117949`}, {0.`, 
2.6108147547664196`, -6.825520586258412`}, {0.`, 
2.7965831676669475`, -7.7877067145546945`}, {0.`, 
2.9711219537904565`, -8.752013771658426`}, {0.`, 
3.1351888993851493`, -9.718148237036544`}, {0.`, 
3.293939712081739`, -10.68516811114236`}, {0.`, 
3.446628748071845`, -11.653175314901679`}, {0.`, 
3.5920179098646257`, -12.622303186432559`}, {0.`, 
3.7327903727452307`, -13.592108433121844`}, {0.`, 
3.869928406663653`, -14.562439560875971`}, {0.`, 
4.001597690199811`, -15.533529200412197`}, {0.`, 
4.129534942532638`, -16.505114420399323`}, {0.`, 
4.254163300278233`, -17.477129926550088`}, {0.`, 
4.375599665341916`, -18.44955221006772`}, {0.`, 
4.493076910338733`, -19.422459628968905`}, {0.`, 
4.607874144591685`, -20.395685734159873`}, {0.`, 
4.720521817734745`, -21.369165045156986`}, {0.`, 
4.82953953367367`, -22.34305776299247`}, {0.`, 
4.936527205777186`, -23.31717399887851`}, {0.`, 
5.0412341567172305`, -24.291538473575017`}, {0.`, 
5.143132427981182`, -25.266201815737293`}, {0.`, 
5.242772179229424`, -26.241097728338207`}, {0.`, 
5.340489084383388`, -27.216187995554275`}, {0.`, 
5.436252607373474`, -28.19147320302235`}, {0.`, 
5.529327468852175`, -29.167018164741794`}, {0.`, 
5.620970068762839`, -30.1426984005079`}, {0.`, 
5.7109731981305`, -31.118531839841786`}, {0.`, 
5.798282312752045`, -32.094610221297664`}, {0.`, 
5.8840721855266`, -33.07082242792449`}, {0.`, 
5.9682420159077125`, -34.04717599344184`}, {0.`, 
6.050344237845955`, -35.023706132963575`}, {0.`, 
6.130492612829591`, -36.00039820370963`}, {0.`, 
6.209350578708569`, -36.97719494314058`}, {0.`, 
6.28665158503886`, -37.95411685855928`}, {0.`, 
6.361486464246535`, -38.93123078697065`}, {0.`, 
6.434993615834652`, -39.908444648006295`}, {0.`, 
6.507118450928904`, -40.88576218773436`}, {0.`, 
6.576974106502235`, -41.86324470707982`}, {0.`, 
6.645172132588883`, -42.84084366692272`}, {0.`, 
6.712120050492588`, -43.818529130831095`}, {0.`, 
6.777210808791073`, -44.796340503962774`}, {0.`, 
6.840300265629204`, -45.774282670423965`}, {0.`, 
6.901715246858553`, -46.752330899619196`}, {0.`, 
6.961726550947702`, -47.73046706604268`}, {0.`, 
7.019479900853515`, -48.70873923615496`}, {0.`, 
7.0754841689826735`, -49.68711230938023`}, {0.`, 
7.130121277110086`, -50.665562927345505`}, {0.`, 
7.1825946876142455`, -51.64413251068211`}, {0.`, 
7.232917000662307`, -52.62281448280182`}, {0.`, 
7.281423908527646`, -53.60158765091907`}, {0.`, 
7.3283329407373525`, -54.58043974952165`}, {0.`, 
7.372421311966208`, -55.55942284038564`}, {0.`, 
7.414565430638978`, -56.538490478210385`}, {0.`, 
7.45509629677926`, -57.517626855782645`}, {0.`, 
7.4927097377859555`, -58.496880202622556`}, {0.`, 
7.528119231731639`, -59.47621439958757`}, {0.`, 
7.561205608406681`, -60.45562949903152`}, {0.`, 
7.591477712629761`, -61.43513727743219`}, {0.`, 
7.618651942266399`, -62.41473476536111`}, {0.`, 
7.643342865646019`, -63.394397028756664`}, {0.`, 
7.665344900214946`, -64.37412464388542`}, {0.`, 
7.683099436495325`, -65.35393925118774`}, {0.`, 
7.699040567200549`, -66.333783796336`}, {0.`, 
7.710320342520651`, -67.3136933138148`}, {0.`, 
7.7169717639518804`, -68.2936453716875`}, {0.`, 
7.720322044320179`, -69.27361901350118`}};
runningAlongSplPts2 = {{8.240321708774308`, 
0.6030461065943664`, -2.7896782912256963`}, {8.342946673301437`, 
0.7051729939221426`, -2.978064991951184`}, {8.443571197077338`, 
0.8053029231483041`, -3.168578357252073`}, {8.54192107926914`, 
0.9031816473503386`, -3.3614440346149688`}, {8.635076592105063`, 
0.9960503758133705`, -3.5592380905697563`}, {8.809079249370352`, 
1.1706262798343168`, -3.9650471212223244`}, {8.965943564156566`, 
1.3300396410428987`, -4.384310070870471`}, {9.208774977927966`, 
1.5934711277976916`, -5.264083218151268`}, {9.42207643862208`, 
1.8350966815610947`, -6.157466240748153`}, {9.603662541131317`, 
2.053636160746735`, -7.064300594880703`}, {9.751906305894746`, 
2.247647623778754`, -7.9827695133271925`}, {9.882918847835354`, 
2.4284146210504787`, -8.906432322400722`}, {10.002895372291128`, 
2.6005194583523474`, -9.83331063396348`}, {10.110371996479996`, 
2.7624356389965503`, -10.763597547463762`}, {10.206804605417373`, 
2.914493557359835`, -11.696734852224068`}, {10.297904186487793`, 
3.0615413920855166`, -12.631206471192929`}, {10.38306764851121`, 
3.202878456319493`, -13.567140675472924`}, {10.46207747628775`, 
3.3373483168922036`, -14.5046209505899`}, {10.53744767076312`, 
3.4676785562120482`, -15.442979739517682`}, {10.6100280136346`, 
3.594757134596561`, -16.382011915313978`}, {10.678851133935797`, 
3.716761071630219`, -17.322001400995394`}, {10.74546993745262`, 
3.8352356774796474`, -18.262596943957522`}, {10.810241212117063`, 
3.95059650672762`, -19.203709005356906`}, {10.87332524097082`, 
4.062966313408351`, -20.145300874258414`}, {10.934880303128919`, 
4.171695736321117`, -21.087420086541442`}, {10.995524828114277`, 
4.277890914635693`, -22.029886069807272`}, {11.05547270589615`, 
4.382036476027874`, -22.97262745462863`}, {11.114522136992173`, 
4.482656475208611`, -23.915808559286386`}, {11.173272248982098`, 
4.581500523976269`, -24.85919484398039`}, {11.231755922249626`, 
4.6783380388471345`, -25.802806089064163`}, {11.290072964094318`, 
4.772668537167861`, -26.746682508649045`}, {11.34844720931438`, 
4.864859381986195`, -27.690765947809133`}, {11.406957151661102`, 
4.9552234287356285`, -28.635017323219813`}, {11.465663430506499`, 
5.043730217486136`, -29.579433511613743`}, {11.524826990792976`, 
5.129777603594175`, -30.52404798240432`}, {11.58432794622796`, 
5.214463086054661`, -31.468763935256096`}, {11.644258492335634`, 
5.297573088700222`, -32.41359326435266`}, {11.70499844430169`, 
5.378187899794813`, -33.35858729935959`}, {11.76631078432877`, 
5.45745645699496`, -34.30365742222447`}, {11.82826328176702`, 
5.535267282382559`, -35.24880718073838`}, {11.891120044231256`, 
5.611147341853812`, -36.194054798941394`}, {11.955078730461135`, 
5.685149070443992`, -37.13937694492589`}, {12.019749560786776`, 
5.757923959354974`, -38.0847454442668`}, {12.08527289544337`, 
5.8292247007167965`, -39.030168464795004`}, {12.15222277091968`, 
5.898280410779112`, -39.975658199701115`}, {12.219981293846793`, 
5.966133139016052`, -40.92117639133262`}, {12.28858532909788`, 
6.03273207900612`, -41.866723566264255`}, {12.358656820041407`, 
6.097211348718264`, -42.81231027601945`}, {12.429926426259255`, 
6.160142251853553`, -43.757910886889626`}, {12.502123269730568`, 
6.22189521439342`, -44.70351889492354`}, {12.575745405048732`, 
6.281876484355865`, -45.64913184120558`}, {12.65079428507417`, 
6.340037036641763`, -46.59474585899781`}, {12.727025635801263`, 
6.396698771551035`, -47.54035560684268`}, {12.8042597347977`, 
6.452104633033133`, -48.48595943584569`}, {12.883494537712615`, 
6.505349579077225`, -49.43152203951566`}, {12.964049247286452`, 
6.5569232299041404`, -50.37706455358017`}, {13.045613343735923`, 
6.607197478999385`, -51.32259093053945`}, {13.128714588015121`, 
6.655431746574516`, -52.26809050978952`}, {13.213618267956626`, 
6.701688867930852`, -53.21352781150671`}, {13.29984575088314`, 
6.746320706046611`, -54.158923002628796`}, {13.387165729730022`, 
6.789538884261847`, -55.10428495770064`}, {13.476573949431037`, 
6.830392756904982`, -56.04955671171308`}, {13.567570474105754`, 
6.869282863961969`, -56.99475777604675`}, {13.659817384838083`, 
6.906562235754413`, -57.93990389105074`}, {13.75389276460174`, 
6.941106297221363`, -58.88497444210553`}, {13.849396231169665`, 
6.973639511267915`, -59.82997140597927`}, {13.946442185640691`, 
7.004068000606431`, -60.77488085761919`}, {14.045402637544885`, 
7.031964771855472`, -61.71967205933739`}, {14.145928852568044`, 
7.056972954421876`, -62.664377518563256`}, {14.247903732383556`, 
7.079682518117448`, -63.60898440551059`}, {14.351499737583108`, 
7.099912607639583`, -64.55347295980003`}, {14.45734671845516`, 
7.116251319265254`, -65.49778820317697`}, {14.564310906423593`, 
7.130620908277714`, -66.4420076005503`}, {14.67349401307929`, 
7.140671746068936`, -67.38602994951326`}, {14.784431260269045`, 
7.1467873922873295`, -68.32988160562158`}, {14.896497028547758`, 
7.149953095788039`, -69.27361901350116`}};
```

Utility Fx

```
x[Pt_] := Pt[[1]]
y[Pt_] := Pt[[2]]
z[Pt_] := Pt[[3]]
```

and "rasterising" between those spline

```
    surfaceRasterizing[StartSpline_, EndSpline_, RunningAlongSpline1_, 
  RunningAlongSpline2_] :=

 Module[{meanCurve, LengthTotalApprox, Length$PtApprox, 
   lenghtFraction, StartPt, EndPt, NewStartPt, NewEndPt, theTransform},

  theRaster = {};
  theMeanCurveList = {};

  (*Getting a lenghtFraction of the total Length*)

  Do[LengthTotalApprox = 
    Total@Table[
      EuclideanDistance[RunningAlongSpline1[[j]], 
       RunningAlongSpline1[[j + 1]]], {j, 1, 
       Length@RunningAlongSpline1 - 1}];
   Length$PtApprox = 
    Total@Table[
      EuclideanDistance[RunningAlongSpline1[[j]], 
       RunningAlongSpline1[[j + 1]]], {j, 1, i - 1}];
   lenghtFraction = Length$PtApprox/LengthTotalApprox;

   (*Getting the mean Curve*)

   meanCurve = 
    Total[{(1 - lenghtFraction)*StartSpline, 
      lenghtFraction*EndSpline}];

   (*Start & End Pts*)
   StartPt = First@meanCurve;
   EndPt = Last@meanCurve;

   NewStartPt = RunningAlongSpline1[[i]];
   NewEndPt = RunningAlongSpline2[[i]];

   (*Rescaling*)

   theTransform = 
    RescalingTransform[{{x@StartPt, x@EndPt}, {y@StartPt, 
       y@EndPt}, {z@StartPt, z@EndPt}}, 
     {{x@NewStartPt, x@NewEndPt}, {y@NewStartPt, 
       y@NewEndPt}, {z@NewStartPt, z@NewEndPt}}];

   (*Compiling*)

   theRaster = Append[theRaster, theTransform /@ meanCurve];
   theMeanCurveList = Append[theMeanCurveList, meanCurve];
, {i, 2, Length@RunningAlongSpline1 - 1}];
theRaster
]
```

Running the stuff:

```
theRaster = 
 surfaceRasterizing[startSplPts, endSplPts, runningAlongSplPts1, 
  runningAlongSplPts2];
```

Visualisation:

```
Graphics3D[{
  {Magenta, 
   BSplineCurve /@ {startSplPts, endSplPts, runningAlongSplPts1, 
     runningAlongSplPts2}},
  (*{Gray, BSplineCurve/@theMeanCurveList}*),
  {Cyan, Point /@ theRaster}, 
  BSplineSurface[Append[Prepend[theRaster, startSplPts], endSplPts]]
  }, PlotRange -> {All, All, All}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Though simplified, the result would be good enough for me my purpose. Only there is the "artefact" where the 2 "running along" splines cross on the y-axis. If I do somewhat understand the causes, I have no idea how to bypass that. Should I use another strategy instead Rescaling? Any Input is really welcomed:)

Thank you!!!

Nearly a month later, I haven't had any success resolving this question. So, back to the basics. let's extract a single BSpline from the previous list:

```
ExempleBSpline = theMeanCurveList[[8]];
RescalingResult = theRaster[[8]];
A1 = First@ExempleBSpline;
A2 = Last@ExempleBSpline;
B1 = First@ExempleRescalingResult;
B2 = Last@ExempleRescalingResult;
```

Here we can observe that the rescaling transform do a real good job on the x & z axes; but a very poor one on the y axis:

```
Table[Graphics3D[{
   {Green, BSplineCurve[ExempleBSpline]}, {Magenta, 
    BSplineCurve[RescalingResult]},
   {Black, Point[{A1, A2, B1, B2}]},
   {Blue, Arrowheads[.015], Arrow[{{A1, B1}, {A2, B2}}]},
   Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{"Start Pt", A1}, {"End Pt", 
      A2}, {"New Start Pt", B1}, {"New End Pt", B2}}
   },
  Axes -> True, Ticks -> None, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, ViewPoint -> vp],
 {vp, {{1, 1, 1}, {0, \[Infinity], 0}, {0, 0, \[Infinity]}}}]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

ok, then why? the rescaling Transform use:

```
RescalingTransform[{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}, {zmin, 
   zmax}}, {{NEWxmin, NEWxmax}, {NEWymin, NEWymax}, {NEWzmin, 
   NEWzmax}}]
```

I do not feed the transformation function with min/max values (as I should), but with start/end points (easier to collect). but it doesn't really affect the result (at least, working with min/max value doesn't solve the issue).

The "negative curvature" is simple enough to understand (even for me ;) we have a negative (NEWymax-NEWymin) divided thought a positive (ymax-ymin). What I described as an "artifact" seem to be explained with dividing through values tending to 0. That make sense, all right, but how do I avoid that?

Let's decompose to 2D, ignoring the z values:

```
{ExempleBSpline2D, RescalingResult2D, StartPt2D, EndPt2D, 
   NewStartPt2D, NewEndPt2D} = 
  ReplaceAll[{x_, y_, z_} :> {x, y}] /@ {ExempleBSpline, 
    ExempleRescalingResult, A1, A2, B1, B2};

Graphics[{
  {Green, Line@ExempleBSpline2D},
  {Magenta, Line@RescalingResult2D}, 
  {Blue, Arrowheads[.015], 
   Arrow[{{StartPt2D, NewStartPt2D}, {EndPt2D, NewEndPt2D}}]},
  Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{"Start Pt", StartPt2D}, {"End Pt", 
     EndPt2D}, {"New Start Pt", NewStartPt2D}, {"New End Pt", 
     NewEndPt2D}}
  }, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Ticks -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

If you translate the "New End Pt" to have an y-value above to the y-value of the "New Start Pt",  then the result curve directly flip over:

```
testTranslation = {0, .2};

Graphics[{
  {Green, Line@ExempleBSpline2D},
  {Magenta, Line@RescalingResult2D}, 
  {Magenta, Dashed, 
   Line@RescalingTransform[{{x@StartPt2D, x@EndPt2D}, {y@StartPt2D, 
        y@EndPt2D}}, {{x@NewStartPt2D, x@NewEndPt2D}, {y@NewStartPt2D,
         y@NewEndPt2D + testTranslation[[2]]}}]@ExempleBSpline2D}, 
  {Blue, Dashed, Arrowheads[.015], 
   Arrow[{EndPt2D, NewEndPt2D + testTranslation}]},
  {Blue, Arrowheads[.015], 
   Arrow[{{StartPt2D, NewStartPt2D}, {EndPt2D, NewEndPt2D}}]},
  Text[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ {{"Start Pt", StartPt2D}, {"End Pt", 
     EndPt2D}, {"New Start Pt", NewStartPt2D}, {"New End Pt", 
     NewEndPt2D}}
  }, Axes -> True, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}, Ticks -> False, 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

what isn't that better... Ideally, I want to keep the general shape of the curve, especially the angles at the extremities. I do understand that it is some kind of specific... and poorly formulated, sorry for that. Thank you.